# How to write .wav file from data using wavio api

Tags: python, wav, numpy-ndarray

I'm using WAVIO python API to write data to a .wav file.
In order to test this api, First I read data .wav file and then I want to generate .wav containing the same data of the input .wav file, but I got an error while writing data to the output wav file.

```
import numpy as np
import wavio

wa = wavio.read("s24.wav")  #Read a .wav file
print("x= "+str(wa.data))   #Data
print("rate= "+str(wa.rate))    #Rate
print("sampwidth= "+str(wa.sampwidth))  #sampwidth
wavio.write("sine24_output", wa.data, wa.rate,wa.sampwidth)   #Error is here
```

Error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Wav2Bytes/wavii.py", line 24, in <module>
    wavio.write("sine24_output", wa.data, wa.rate,wa.sampwidth)   #Write a .wav file. Error is here
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\wavio.py", line 363, in write
    vmin, vmax = scale
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the argument's name `sampwidth`. According to the [docs](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio), there are 5 arguments, if you don't specify the name `sampwidth`, it will instead set `scale` to `wa.sampwidth`. Anyway just use this:

`wavio.write("sine24_output", wa.data, wa.rate,sampwidth=wa.sampwidth)`